# the connections order is ignored on Windows 8.1 pro

Tags: networking, windows-8.1

I am connecting to both a wired and wireless networks. The wired network should be used for a virtual machine and the wireless for internet on the host.

In order to set this up, I changed the order of the `Connections` in the Advanced Settings:
[image]

The issue is that the settings are ignored and the Ethernet is used on the host as well. When I try to access an internet site, the Ethernet connection is used an this causes errors. If I unplug the Ethernet, I can surf the web again but the Virtual machine can not access its resources.

Comment: What software do you use for virtual machine?

Comment: It is VMWare Workstation 11. But I doubt that this is the root of the issue.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/803310/how-do-i-bridge-my-internal-wireless-card-to-vmware-workstation-10-guest-and-sti

Answer (score 2):

These 'Advanced Settings' just doesn't do what you want, they just change network adapter order when some software lists adapters but they don't change connection priority as you need.

You need instead to check each of your network connection properties, then check `TCP/IP properties -> Advanced`, then disable `Automatic metric` checkbox and set `Interface metric` to a number, the interface with **lowest** metric value has priority.

Comment: thank you for your answer. unfortunately I can not check that as I do not use a windows laptop anymore. If someone can confirm that this does indeed work, I'll check the correct answer box